# ZOTAC GeForce GTX 780 crashes

Tags: power-supply, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

Three to four days ago I bought a ZOTAC GeForce GTX 780 graphics card. I installed it and everything seemed to work properly. But now when I play games (AC:unity, Splinter Cell: Black list, COD: Advanced warfare), after a few minutes of playing the game crashes. First my USB devices shut down and then the computer restarts (or I have to reset it).

In Event Viewer I see this critical error, event ID 41 (Kernel-Power):

> "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."

So, I believe there is something wrong with my power supply.
This is my PSU's specifications:

[image: Photo of the PSU including specs]

These are my graphics card's requirements:

> Minimum 600W (with minimum 12V current rating of 42A)

I don't know about PSUs at all. Can anybody please tell me that should I change the PSU or is there a problem with the installation of the the card itself (e.g. power cables or something else)?

My system specifications:

- i7 870 @ 2.93 GHz
- RAM 14 GB DDR3
- Windows 8.1 - x64
- HDD 2 TB + SSD 256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the photo, it looks like your PSU is not powerful enough to support that graphics card.

It shows maximum 25A on the 12v rail, compared to your stated requirement of 42A

[image]

tbh, I think you would struggle to find any 600W PSU capable of 42A on the 12v rail. They're usually more like 32A at 600W, so you're more likely to be looking for something around 1000W or so.

Best would be to ask at a local computer store. Tell them what card it's for & they will better be able to help you choose the correct PSU.

Comment: Yesterday spend 250$ and bought a "CORSAIR AXi series AX860i 860W" and still has the problem :fou:

Comment: ouch - that is not an underpowered PSU, by any means. Sorry that didn't work. Maybe have a look at [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) & see if you can tell what's going out of bounds.